# CSS won't stay put

Tags: html, css

I am making my first webpage and am having trouble positioning elements. They keep overlapping each other when I resize the browser. The title is positioned absolute, but this means it overlaps the image at the top. I cant get it into position by any other means. Can anyone help?

My question wasn't answered properly the first time.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-width: 1024px;
  min-height: 760px;
  max-height: 760px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.header img {
  min-width: 77%;
  max-width: 77%;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 23%;
}

#cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#cont .header {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 23%;
  color: teal;
  font-size: 63px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="./new 1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <img src="C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\Coding\Images\guitar_banner.jpg" alt="Dunc's guitar lessons in Isleworth" />

      <div id="cont">
        <div class="top-left">Dunc's<br/> Guitar<br/> Lessons</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: where do you want the title and image to be ?

Comment: Please provide screenshot or at least prototype, because other people don’t know how it should be show on the screen.

Comment: Provide screenshot

Comment: can you provide an image of how it looks and how it should look?

Comment: `position:absolute` has its place, but it should be used sparingly, for exactly this reason. Any element that is positioned in this manner is removed from the normal document flow. Working out how to position elements using the natural flow of the document will aid you greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this ? please tell me if i wrong.

[image: result]

Here your css code.

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
    min-width: 1024px;
    min-height: 760px;
    max-height: 760px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    }

    .header img {
    min-width: 77%;
    max-width: 77%;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 23%;
    }

    #cont {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    }

    #cont .header {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    }

    .top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: 23%;
    color: teal;
    font-size: 63px;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And here your html code.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div id="cont">
            <div class="top-left">Dunc's<br/> Guitar<br/> Lessons</div>
        </div>
            <img src="C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\Coding\Images\guitar_banner.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this help you.
Good luck.